# Which brake levers and brake calipers to replace Sram s-series HRD700 (postmount)?

Tags: shimano, brakes, sram, caliper

I own a Giant TCX SLR 1 from 2014, with Sram s-series HRD700 brakes (post mount right?) and 10 speed sram force transmission. Discs are 140mm rear and 160mm front.

My brakes are completly gone and I am looking to replace levers and calipers. I am a bit lost regarding brake compatibility. What levers and calipers / group would you advise for an affordable brake replacement?

Original s-series brakes sell for 600 € which seems expensive and I was not completly happy with them. Is there other better sram options? Should I swap for shimano?

If I swap to a Tiagra or GRX group,will the levers be compatible with Shimano MTB calipers?  For example BR-MT410 (DEORE) or BR-MT520  calipers are post mount but I am unsure about lever and rotor compatibility..

Thanks for your help

Comment: One significant compatibility issue is ensuring that the brake fluid is compatible with all the parts (brake levers, hydraulic hose/tubing, calipers).  In general (could be exceptions) SRAM uses DOT 3 brake fluid and Shimano uses a mineral oil based fluid.  NOT COMPATIBLE with each other.  So something to think about.

Comment: Yes, I am not thinking of mixing shimano and sram it would be either : sram levers and calipers + dot or shimano levers and calipers + mineral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot here revolves around how much value you place on keeping the bike set up with SRAM 10.

Keeping SRAM 10 road bikes going is increasingly difficult. Most of the legacy support components for them that are still made are Red-level, and there are often availability gaps. If your Doubletaps and  derailleurs have 10 years of use on them and are wearing out as they do, there's basically no way it's worth it.

If on the other hand everything else was good and the only thing you needed were new calipers for whatever reason to keep the bike going, that's not really a problem. Just get the Apex HRD post mount calipers. Note though that there's probably a replacement seal and piston kit available for your HRD700 set if that were the issue.

In Shimano land, yes the hydraulic road STIs work with post mount mountain brakes like they were meant to do so. The first Shimano road hydros basically were just M785 calipers with different cosmetics. But if you were to go this direction, you're talking about buying STIs, both brakes, and the RD no matter what. SRAM and Shimano front derailleurs and shifters interchange somewhat, so you could perhaps get away there. Your 10-speed cranks will also typically be able to work with 11 if you went that direction, since you're also somewhat boxed in if you were to only be looking at 10-speed Shimano road groups.

If the SRAM rotors you have are still good, it won't really hurt anything to put the new calipers on them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

RD and cranks were changed 2 years ago (still force 10s). Regarding the brakes, STIs and calipers are 10 y old and I need to change both. I will probably need wheel replacement too..
So if I follow you, not worth it to replace STIs and calipers and stay sram 10, because that will not be future proof.. I kinda excpeted this answer.

I am quite limited by my RD for gearing so I would in fact be interested in swapping the whole group.

GRX 600 or 105 R7000 2x11 ? Do you see a better option? They are around 700€, would just need to swap calipers for postmount ones. Which one should I look for ? Deore MT410?

Comment: Just FYI, exchange sites do not work like a traditional chat forum. The method used to acknowledge a good answer is to upvote it using the voting buttons. AND as the owner of the question, you have the ability to choose the answer that answers your question the best. Suggest taking the “Tour” which explains all this.  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Thans @TedHohl, but I cannot vote apparently (lack of reputation)

Comment: yep, it takes 15 rep to be able to vote up, but I though that was not applied on your own question (learn something every day).  You should still be able to mark the accepted answer regardless of reputation (only the questioner and possibly a moderator can do this).